# MongoDB .NET Driver - Aggregation query with calculation based on category

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to calculate monthly income and monthly spending.
My DB collection "transactions" consists of documents, here is `TransactionModel`:

```cs
public record TransactionModel  
{
     public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
     public double Price { get; set; }
     public string Category { get; set; }
     public DateTime Date { get; set; }
     ....
}
```

I am using `myCollection.Aggregate().Match(filter)` and it filters my list by date (and it works). Still, I couldn't find the correct syntax to group all the filtered transactions into two groups: "Income" which is `Category == "Income"` and "MonthlySpent" which is all rest categories and then calculate the sum of each group.

I am trying to find a solution the "C# way". Thanks!

Here is what I came up with so far:
After I filtered the transactions by date, I tried to use projection to add a property which will tell me for each transaction if its category is income or not. Im kinda stuck from here.

```cs
var monthlyTransactions = await transactionCollection.Aggregate()
    .Match(monthlyNonIncomefilter)
    .Project(priceProjection)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This is the monthly filter & the projection:

```cs
var monthlyNonIncomefilter = filterBuilder.Gte(x => x.Date, fromDate) &
    filterBuilder.Lte(x => x.Date, toDate);

var priceProjection = projectionBuilder.Expression(u => new
{
    Price = u.Price,
    Type = u.Category == "Income" ? "Income" : "MonthlySpent"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late to the answer.

You need a `$group` stage to group the documents by `Category` and perform the sum for the `Price`.

For MongoDB .NET driver, you can achieve with [IAggregateFluentExtensions.Group<TResult, TKey, TNewResult> Method (IAggregateFluent, Expression<Func<TResult, TKey>>, Expression<Func<IGrouping<TKey, TResult>, TNewResult>>)](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IAggregateFluentExtensions_Group__3.htm).

```cs
var monthlyTransactions = await transactionCollection.Aggregate()
    .Match(monthlyNonIncomefilter)
    .Group(
        x => x.Category == "Income" ? "Income" : "MonthlySpent",
        group => new
        {
            Type = group.Key,
            Price = group.Sum(x => x.Price)
        })
    .ToListAsync();
```

> Demo

[image]